# JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file /index.jsp

Tags: spring, jsf, war, mime-types

I'm working on a Java Dynamic Web  Project where I want to integrate Spring IoC 4.1.6, JSF 2.2.x and PrimeFaces 5.1. But I'm stuck at the moment getting the below error when I try to request any page I have created like `/pages/index.jsf`.

> com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getMimeType JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file /index.jsp.  To resolve  this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.

I'm using the following dependencies in **pom.xml**

```
<!-- JSF dependencies -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Primefaces -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

At first I have tried to add mime-type to my web.xml config file but that won't solve my problem. I'm wondering if it has to do with my dependencies.

I have only the JSF servlet in my `web.xml`:

```
<!-- JSF Servlet is defined to container -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Mapping with servlet and url for the http requests. -->
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/mxvrvvl0p/ also I have edited my main post with the servlets mapping . This is my first attempt on integrating all these frameworks for a school project and yes.. so there are some unclear things for me at the moment

Comment: Project structure looks strange. Looks a mix of Eclipse's "Dynamic Web Project" and Maven's "Web Application Project". Which Maven plugin are you using? Eclipse's builtin? Can you try to export it to a WAR file and check if there's actually an `index.xhtml` file in there? Edit: Oh, it's a school project? I sugges taking this up with your tutor and/or classmates.

Comment: Seems like I managed to solve the problem . Yes it had to do with the exported war. Seems like there was an index.html created inside WAR file from an older backed up file that I had in my project. I have deleted both projectName-snapshopt folder and projectName-snapshot.war from inside my project location and builded another clean war(without the older index.html file which was in conflict with my other index.xhtml)